# How to do Pagination in JDBC using oracle 11 g

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle11g

How can I do pagination in JDBC using Oracle database?. I know that it's possible do by query. But I wan to do without query using only JDBC method.

Comment: You could try using a high level framework like Spring Data JPA. This would support Pagination out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do pagination with just JDBC methods. It's just something that JDBC isn't meant to handle (it's meant to connect to databases, execute your queries blindly and return results).

You'll have to work it out with queries, or as Tobias suggested, using a framework that gives you pagination out of the box.

Comment: If there is no ways of doing pagination in JDBC without query , Then what is the use of setFetchSize(int n) method of statement . This method only fetch some 1st n data from the database but if we want to fetch another 2nd n data from the database then there is no way of doing this then what is the use of  setFetchSize(int n).

Comment: It's a hint to the driver (who is free to ignore it) on how many rows should be fetched over the network, when more data is needed to fill a `ResultSet`. It has nothing to do with the actual size of the query's results.

Answer (score -1):

You can set Statement statement as

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

st.setFetchSize(int rows);
st.setMaxRows(int maxRows);

st.setFetchDirection(int direction)
```

Comment: That won't help. `setFetchSize()` only hints how many more rows should be fetched over the network, and `setMaxRows()` just sets a maximum amount of rows that the `ResultSet` is allowed to process (never mind what the actual rowcount is).